# Trouble using .combine with cforest

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-forest

Hello I have an issue with parallelizing *cforest* in R.

I have been trying to create a classification model using the *cforest* function the *party* package. I would like this to be run in parallel in several cores on my computer. I already successfully did this with the *randomForest* algorithm combined with *.combine* and *foreach*:

```
    library(doParallel)
    library(foreach)
    library(randomForest)
    library(party)        
    cl <- (5)
    registerDoParallel(cl)        
    set.seed(1234)
    abs_pos_dat_all <- read.csv('all_abs_pos_predictors_3_20_13_for_R.txt');
    abs_pos_dat <- abs_pos_dat_all[1:10000,]
    train_test_indices <- sample(2,nrow(abs_pos_dat), replace=TRUE, prob=c(.7,.3));
    ref_polarity_dat <- read.table('ref_polarity_3_20_13_for_R.txt');
    ref_polarity_dat <- factor(ref_polarity_dat[1:10000,])
    ref_polarity_train <- ref_polarity_dat[train_test_indices==1]
abs_pos_train[,1] <- ordered(abs_pos_train[,1], labels = c("Buried","Part buried","Exposed"))
abs_pos_train[,2] <- ordered(abs_pos_train[,2], labels = c("Helix","Strand","Other"))
Flank_FA_labels <- c("bur bur","bur part","part part","bur exp","part exp", "exp exp")
Flank_Struc_labels <- c("helix helix","helix strand","strand strand","helix other","strand other", "other other")
Flank_Polarity_labels <- c("polar polar", "polar nonpolar", "non polar non polar" )

    for(i in 1:length(Flank_FA_labels)){
        abs_pos_train[,i] <- ordered(abs_pos_train[,2+i], labels = Flank_FA_labels) 
        abs_pos_train[,8+i] <- ordered(abs_pos_train[,8+i], labels = Flank_Polarity_labels)
        abs_pos_train[,14+i] <- ordered(abs_pos_train[,14+i], labels = Flank_Struc_labels)
    }

   colnames(abs_pos_train) <- c("ref_FA", "ref_struc", "Np1Flank_FA", "Np2Flank_FA", "Np3Flank_FA", "Np4Flank_FA", "Np5Flank_FA", "Np6Flank_FA", "Np1Flank_Struc", "Np2Flank_Struc", "Np3Flank_Struc", "Np4Flank_Struc", "Np5Flank_Struc", "Np6Flank_Struc", "Np1Flank_P_NP","Np2Flank_P_NP", "Np3Flank_P_NP", "Np4Flank_P_NP", "Np5Flank_P_NP", "Np6Flank_P_NP")


    abs_pos_random_forest <<- foreach(ntree=rep(100, 5), .combine=combine, .packages='randomForest') %dopar%  randomForest(ref_polarity_train~.,data = abs_pos_train, ntree=ntree)
```

However, when I use the same syntax with *cforest*, I get the following error:

```
    abs_pos_inference_random_forest <<- foreach(ntree=rep(20, 6), 
    .combine=combine , .packages='party') %dopar%  cforest(ref_polarity_train~.,
    data = abs_pos_train, controls = cforest_unbiased(ntree=ntree, mtry = 1))
    error calling combine function:
    <simpleError in fun(result.1, result.2): 
    Argument must be a list of randomForest objects>
```

I can't figure out why .combine is looking for *randomForest* objects instead of *cforest* objects, or at least why .combine doesn't automatically recognize the type of object that is being combined, if they are all the output of a single function.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the same error message executing:

```
library(randomForest)
combine(1,2,3)
```

Presumably the randomForest package was loaded, so the randomForest `combine` function was passed to foreach via the `.combine` option.  If `combine` was a generic function with methods defined by both randomForest and party, then it might have worked as you expected.  But it's not generic; it's just a regular function defined in the randomForest package, and foreach dutifully called it.

I'm not very familiar with the party package, so I don't know if it includes an equivalent function.

Comment: I see. That makes quite a bit of sense. I am currently looking into alternative methods for combining parallel computations of forests from the cforest package. Thanks!

Comment: @IanBorukhovich Hello, I'm looking for that too. Please have you find something ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I ended up using matlab then using decision trees, I wrote some custom code to parallel process running trees and gathering meta data.